# "Loading of the ImageList did not succeed" exception occured

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I am having issue on the statement below while loading the ImageStream.

```
this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageS‌​tream")));
```

Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.  --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Loading of the ImageList did not
>   succeed

When i browsed and saw the ImageStream object it was null. It has thrown the exception above relating with "mscorelib" too.

Any suggestions and comments will be much appreciated

Comment: Tell please, what are you trying to do? This code is what winforms designer produces in `InitializeComponents()` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21604451/1997232)). If you don't have `"imageList1.ImageStream"` in form1.resx, then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the ugly code at the bottom, but I'm a results based programmer that has to make things work NOW.

I ran into an emergency with a runtime error on InitializeComponent();  It failed and my winforms app was a blank screen.

Stepping through Lots of code it seemed that this call:

this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageS‌​tream")));

In the designer.cs generate file is where it failed.

Nothing would fix it from the designer.  In an emergency I simply created the image list by hand Before the initializeComponent() call.

I'm sure it has something to do with the complexity of the winform and its designer generation in the visual studio IDE - but can't prove it as I need results NOW.

So if you take your image list off the form, add the images as "embedded resources" then load up your image list by hand.  I "think" the designer didn't actually embed the resource.

```
ilssC                  = new ImageList();
ilssC.ColorDepth       = System.Windows.Forms.ColorDepth.Depth16Bit;
ilssC.ImageSize        = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 150);
ilssC.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
Assembly myAssembly    = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream myStream        = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars00.jpg");
Bitmap bmp             = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars00.jpg",bmp);
myStream               = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars01a.jpg");
bmp                    = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars01a.jpg",bmp);
myStream               = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars02a.jpg");
bmp                    = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars02a.jpg", bmp);
myStream               = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars03a.jpg");
bmp                    = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars03a.jpg", bmp);
myStream               = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars04a.jpg");
bmp                    = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars04a.jpg", bmp);
myStream               = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SafeEnv.Resources.ssbars05a.jpg");
bmp                    = new Bitmap(myStream);
ilssC.Images.Add         ("ssbars05a.jpg", bmp);
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (0, "ssbars00.jpg");
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (1, "ssbars01a.jpg");
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (2, "ssbars02a.jpg");
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (3, "ssbars03a.jpg");
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (4, "ssbars04a.jpg");
ilssC.Images.SetKeyName  (5, "ssbars05a.jpg");
```

Comment: wow 02/02/2023 I ran into the same problem.  i added the images as embedded resources and it seems to have worked.  maybe that was my problem back in 2018

Answer (score -2):

I dont understand why you are using  **ImageStream**

I prefer to use

```
HIMAGELIST ImageList_Create(
  int cx,
  int cy,
  UINT flags,
  int cInitial,
  int cGrow
);
```

and then you can allocate your images right before load.

Comment: This question was about C# code.  ImageList_Create is part of the Windows API.