# ImageList created in Designer - Where is the code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A while ago I used the Designer to create an `ImageList` for a `ListView`. Now I'm looking for those images and the code controlling the `ImageList` but can't find it. "**Find all References**" doesn't show all of it (I thought it would be in `InitializeComponent`).

I can use the Designer to set the `ImageSize`, but can't find that anywhere in the code. Not only that - but if I add it manually after the call to `InitializeComponent` - the images disappear at runtime.

I can't find the images anywhere in **Solution Explorer** either.

To be clear - the images *do* show at runtime.

Comment: Do you know, if you import images into `ImagesList` by using designer, then they are saved in form resources, right?

Comment: @Sinatr No. I didn't know where. But anyway, They don't appear in the **Resources** - neither in the Resources-Designer, nor in the Resources-Folder.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks. It's there. But when does the application read that into the ImageList? Also - You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add resource to a form (`ImageList`, form `Icon`, etc), it will be saved in the form resources (resx-file).

They are automatically loaded in `InitializeComponent()` method, which is called in the form constructor.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    ...
    this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
    ...
    this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
    ...
 }
```